# reactjs,how to deal with user event trigger multiple times in short time?

Tags: reactjs

I use `react.js` + `es6` + `webpack` to develop my application.

recently, I find if I click a button multiple times in short time, the `click` handler will trigger multiple times.

I think it's a common case, code snippet like this:

```
@debounce()
  onMidCardClick(url) {
    console.count('onMidCardClick trigger times : ');
    window.location.href = url;
  }
```

before navigate to the url address, `onMidCardClick` event handler will triggers multiple times.

So, my way is create a `debounce.decorator.js` to handle this situation.
I think my way's advantage is easy to read and keep maintainability.

My question is:

**1. Is it necessary to handle this? I mean, maybe `react` synthetic event will handle this for me?**

**2. My application has many events, I add `debounce` decorator for many of them. I test it, it works fine, but I am not sure I am correct. Because I saw many applications not deal with this.**

Comment: check this : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

Comment: @challenger yeah. I use it. But, my question is not about how to implement

Comment: react doesn't handle that...some times like when you have loader, you can cancel the new requests, but in this case you need to handle it.. in the constructor add this this.onMidCardClick = _.debounce(this.onMidCardClick.bind(this), 500)

Answer (score 0):

No, all you need to do is, the moment user clicks a button, disable the button till you get the response. You can also disable other buttons too if required. Ex.

```
<button type="button" disabled={!this.clicked}>Button</button>
```

Comment: I know, but it's just fit html tag which has `disabled` property, what if `div`, `li`? Also, I can create a react component which has `disabled` props for this. But this is another topic.

Comment: You mean click events set up on div or li ?

Answer (score 0):

From a usability point of view, if the user clicks on a button/li/div element and you are executing some logic, it is better to give a visual indicator that some processing is happening, with a loader or a progress bar.

You can write a react component for a full page loader like [this](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html) and show it to the user, which effectively prevents the user from clicking the element again while giving a visual clue as well.

Comment: yeah, can do that. but this way maybe just fit ajax loading indicator. For url or router navigate, I think it's not fit.

Comment: Even for router/URL navigation, you can still show a full screen loader or some sort of indicator (the red line progress bar at the top of the page on YouTube on navigation, the blue line progress bar at the top of the page on GitHub navigation) so that user knows the button click was successful and the action is in progress. In most cases, lack of visual cues is what makes the users to click the button more than once.

Comment: What if boss don't want some sort of indicator when navigate?